# How to do recording in NightwatchJS?

Tags: javascript, selenium, css-selectors, nightwatch.js

I’m using `Nightwatch` to do test End-to-End to our web application; I ‘use Resurrectio to record, but when I copy the code Exported `NightwatchJS` in my file test, I run the test but he was unable to know the elements, I got this error

> Timed out while waiting for element to be present for 1000
>   milliseconds. expected "found" but got: "not found"

Also I’m looking for other tools to record in `NightwatchJS`